# How to insert and shift the cell right?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub int 
    Range(“C” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Insert Shift:=xlRight
End sub
```

I get a runtime error on this line. How do I fix it to insert a cell and shift the data to the right or to column D?

Comment: `xlShiftToRight`. See the [`Range.Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert) documentation.

Comment: Also, consider renaming your sub to avoid confusion with [`Int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/int-fix-functions), and fix the quotes around `C` (should be straight quotes, `"C"`).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thanks, didn't realize it was a reserved name - insert `:facepalm:` emoji :) - but that's my pass for the day since it's Friday.

Answer (score 4):

Per [`Range.Insert` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.insert), the `Shift` parameter takes an argument of type [`XlInsertShiftDirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlinsertshiftdirection), which defines the following values:

```
xlShiftDown     -4121   Shift cells down.
xlShiftToRight  -4161   Shift cells to the right.
```

<s>The run-time error you got, should have been caught at compile-time. Make sure every module always has `Option Explicit` at the top, and always declare all variables you use.</s> (`xlRight` does exist, just not in the `XlInsertShiftDirection` enum)